# 2.8 Installed addon not in list

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to install [MB-Lab](https://github.com/animate1978/MB-Lab/releases) which is an addon that is listed as working,  according to this [list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10V8mwXJaqM3JhQXEC0iTh8jAqXOXQAoeG6Tyb_zZgk0/edit#gid=0). When installing it, a confirmation message is printed. [image]I've tried all 3 versions for 2.8 and I'm using a blender version from the 14.02.2019. I also had success installing other addons in 2.8.

It would help too, if you to install it yourself and comment whether it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same problem: Unzip, rename the folder without any dots (-> . <-) in it and insert it to the other addons manually